# Updating 10 million rows while having a check with another table

Tags: mysql, mysql-python

There are 12 million rows in table A and 10 million in table B.
Now both these table have a common field, say user_id.

Now I've added a column in table A to add the primary key of B.

So the Tables are something like this

```
Table A
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| b_id        | int (11)     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Table B
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id     | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Now I want to update the b_id in table A. In order to do that, I had written the following query:

```
update A
set A.b_id = (select B.id from B
and A.user_id = B.user_id
);
```

But even after indexing it and doing it in a chunks of 100K, its taking a really long time(around 3 min each).

Is there a better and faster way to update it?

Comment: mysql or sql-server, use proper tags

Comment: Isn't joins more expensive.

Comment: is `b.user_id` indexed? it doesn't look like it is. a composite index on `(b.user_id, b.id)` should help

Comment: @FuzzyTree Yes, it is

Comment: `select B.id from B and A.user_id = B.user_id` – does that syntax even work …?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
update A
SET A.b_id = B.id
FROM Table A
INNER JOIN TABLE B ON A.user_id = B.user_id
```

Make sure you have indexes setup on the user_id columns.

Can't comment yet: JOINS are historically faster in Mysql as long as there isn't duplicated data.

Comment: Isn't Join very expensive in this scenario since we have huge amount of data. Also, I'm concern about the memory footprint.

Comment: I spent quite a lot of time to find the right query. And this one worked the best. Thanks Blak